# How do I resolve oracle jdbc proxy class error in Evosuite generated tests?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, syntax-error, driver, evosuite

I've written a JDBC driver and I'm trying to use Evosuite to generate the tests for it.
I'm using the following command line:

```
mvn -Dcores=5 -DmemoryInMB=5000  -Dmock_if_no_generator=false -DextraArgs='  -Dmock_if_no_generator=false -Dskip_covered=true Duse_separate_classloader=false -Dmax_recursion=50 -Dlocal_search_restore_coverage=true -Duse_existing_coverage=true -Dsandbox=false -Dsort_calls=true 'evosuite:generate
```

The code that is generated is below:

```
 oracle.1jdbc.1replay.1driver.1NonTxnReplayableBase.2java.1sql.1DatabaseMetaData...Proxy oracle_1jdbc_1replay_1driver_1NonTxnReplayableBase_2java_1sql_1DatabaseMetaData___Proxy0 = new oracle.1jdbc.1replay.1driver.1NonTxnReplayableBase.2java.1sql.1DatabaseMetaData...Proxy((DatabaseMetaData) null, "k-{`1N&KKC", proxyFactory0, hashtable0);
```

and I'm getting the following error on the first line:
:[4618,7] not a statement
:[4618,13] ';' expected
(getting this error three times on the same line)

I was hoping to turn off the mocking but it didn't work it seems.

I'll try to see if I can provide more details later, but any initial thoughts from anyone?

Thanks!

Comment: By the way I'm using JDK7, and the tests are generated for JDK8 I know.  Perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: I've also tried changing the syntax to       oracle1.jdbc1._1replay._1driver._1TxnReplayableBase._2oracle._1jdbc._1internal.1AdditionalDatabaseMetaData.Proxy oracle_1jdbc_1replay_1driver_1TxnReplayableBase_2oracle_1jdbc_1internal_1AdditionalDatabaseMetaData___Proxy0 = new oracle.1jdbc.1replay.1driver.1TxnReplayableBase.2oracle.1jdbc.1internal.1AdditionalDatabaseMetaData...Proxy((AdditionalDatabaseMetaData) null, (Object) null, proxyFactory0, hashtable0);

but it cannot find the classes starting with oracle1 .  Why does Evosuite create this if it doesnt exist and doesnt provide them itseld?